# android AVD connection refused on every other launch

Tags: android, android-studio, connectionexception

Every other time I launch my app in an AVD I get this happy little error popping up:

```java
Error running app:
Unable to open debugger port (localhost:8611): java.net.ConnectionException "Connection refused"
```

(would have posted a screenshot, but my reputation does not allow it)

It doesn't break anything, and after a couple relaunches it's back on track, but it's starting to annoy me. Does anyone know how to fix this? And I'm looking for a permanent fix, not a fix that would require me to do ten things [over](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28283087/unable-to-open-debugger-port-java-net-connectexception-connection-refused) and [over](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28135735/unable-to-open-debug-port-java-net-socketexception-connection-refused-andro) again [every time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661166/debugging-java-process-using-intellij-connects-to-socket-but-not-to-target-vm) this happens

Android Studio version 1.5.1 on Debian 8.2 using Oracle's java 1.8.0_66.

Also, to clarify, this is not an issue with my code. I can launch a completely empty project and still get this error popping up to say hi.

---

Running `adb start-server` in a standalone terminal yields the following:

```bash
cytodev@GE72-2QE:~$ adb start-server
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
```

This uses a different port than the debugger port Android Studio uses, but I'm guessing that is normal.

Comment: I get this on Windows also with Android Studio 1.5.1

Comment: Have you tried enabling ADB integration in Android Studio? Go to Tools -> Android and it will be there.

Comment: @ApirakLunla, it is checked, so I assume it is enabled.

Comment: what do you get when you run adb start-server?

Comment: @ApirakLunla, updated the question.

Answer (score 2):

There is an issue around IP v6 and how localhost is handled.
To fix the problem you will need to modify host file - see instruction.
(I don't deal much with Linux but I think it's similar configuration for both Windows and Linux)

Windows (Must open with administrator permission)

1. locate host file - C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts
2. uncomment (remove #) the following line: 
   `#    ::1             localhost`

Linux (Must open with root)

1. locate host file - /etc/hosts
2. either add or uncomment ::1 localhost to the configuration file

Comment: Forcing a loopback of `::1` to `localhost` did not fix the issue as of just now, I will need some additional time along with reboots to confirm it. As far as your Linux instructions go, you're not at all far off. Debian does not have a commented line for `::1` but it was spot on.

Comment: It's been awhile, but this did not fix it for me.